# Cant show custom fragment(kotlin, androidx, dagger 2)

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, androidx

I can not figure out how to show a custom fragment with the following:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    //...
}

class LoginFragment : BaseFragment() {
    //...
    companion object {
        var newInstance = LoginFragment()
    }
    //...
}

class AuthActivity ...{
    //...
    public override fun onStart() {
        //...
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.screenContainer, LoginFragment.newInstance).commit()
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

> Type mismatch: inferred type is LoginFragment but Fragment was
>   expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DaggerFragment` extends `android.app.Fragment` or the support `Fragment` while you need to use the *AndroidX* `Fragment`.

You have to use `dagger.android.support.DaggerFragment` and enable the jetifier in your *gradle.properties*:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```